# How to I Document User Rights on an existing Linux System?

Tags: linux, permissions, command-line-interface, documentation, user-accounts

Need to document user rights on an existing Linux system.

What commands, actions, etc. will allow me to gather complete user profiles?

**User rights include, but are not limited to:**

  File/Directory: Read, Write, Execute and Delete

  Access: Root, su, sudo

  Groups/Roles: wheel

  Connections: Local, Remote

**User types include, but are not limited to:** Anonymous, Authenticated, System

Comment: Looks like you are trying to gather Windows style profiles.  That is not the model used by Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rights

- File/Directory: Read, Write, Execute and Delete

  - Use the find command to locate all files/directories either  owned by the user 
    or with group set to a group the user is a member of. You'll need to script this.
- Access Root, su, sudo.

  - inspect /etc/passwd for root equivalence.
  - inspect sudoers config file
- Groups/Roles: wheel

  - inspect /etc/group for membership of privileged groups.
  - I don't think wheel group is commonly used on Linux
- Connections: Local, Remote

  - inspect iptables for restrictions
  - inpsect /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny
  - inspect sshd_config for AllowedUSer and other restrictions
  - ditto for ftpd config, samba config etc

User types

AFAIK User types of anonymous, authenticated and system are not commonplace concepts on Linux. You probably would put usernames such as "nobody", "nfsnobody", "apache" amongst those used for access by unauthenticated anonymous users.

In general, this is a lot of work and you probably should instead be looking for a security auditing tool. There are certainly commercial tools, I used one in the past that identified insecure users amongst many other things. It was hard work to keep on top of. There are free or open-source security auditing tools too.